# create a list of images related to product on product listing page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-list, media-images

I want to show show a list of all product images of that specific product below description in a loop.

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler as GalleryReadHandler; class Gallery

```
{ protected $galleryReadHandler; public function __construct( GalleryReadHandler $galleryReadHandler ) { $this->galleryReadHandler = $galleryReadHandler; } /** Add image gallery to $product */ public function addGallery($product) { $this->galleryReadHandler->execute($product); } }
```

iam still confused that where i have to get these coding and in which particular files...like where to use these coding in which files
 This is what i want

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more detail to your question. What have you tried already? What errors have you seen?

Comment: use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler as GalleryReadHandler;

class Gallery
{
    protected $galleryReadHandler;

    public function __construct(
        GalleryReadHandler $galleryReadHandler
    )
    {
        $this->galleryReadHandler = $galleryReadHandler;
    }

    /** Add image gallery to $product */
    public function addGallery($product)
    {
        $this->galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
    }
}

iam still confused that where i have to get these coding and in which particular files...like where to use these coding in which files

Comment: You need to add this to the question.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: any reply please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it using below code.
path to file: module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view

edit:attribute.html

This is default Code:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code)) ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code) : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div class="product attribute <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_className?>">
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue;
   if($_className=='description')
   {
    ?>

    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
   $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); 
    foreach($images as $child){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add after

```
<div class="value" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue;


<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attributeValue;
   if($_className=='description')
   {
    ?>

    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
   $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); 
    foreach($images as $child){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You will get a list of product images on product listing page as shown in below image:
[image]